# Java `Cannot Find Symbol`

Tags: java, csv

I am getting an error in line: `generateCsvFile("c:\\test.csv");`:

[image]

I am trying to change my current program's output from a text field to `csv` file by following  [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/). 
I added the imports and then 
I added the line `generateCsvFile("c:\\test.csv");` to my main, and that is when I got this error... Why so?

Note: I am a beginner

Comment: Looks like you just need to define a static generateCsvFile() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that the line generateCsvFile("c:\test.csv"); is calling a function named generateCsvFile which is not a predefined function, so you will need to make a function named that. And if you see the tutorial, after that line the function generateCsvFile() is defined so unless you define it you cannot call it and that's why it is giving error. Once you add that part your error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and define either a static function using `private static void generateCSVFile(String fileName)` or a function `public void generateCSVFile(String fileName)`in some class `ABC` and call it using `ObjectofClassABC.generateCSVFile(string fileName)`